# Date format in PACT-Test is ignored and fails (Java 17)

Tags: kotlin, pact, matcher

We have an issue that after migration some Pact tests fail. It seems that the test ignores the matching rule for the date in contract.

Matching rule:

```
          "$.entity.month": {
            "matchers": [
              {
                "match": "date",
                "format": "yyyy-MM"
              }
            ],
```

Maven dependency for Pact:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact</groupId>
            <artifactId>consumer</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.24</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
            <artifactId>java8</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.24</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.consumer</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.24</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>au.com.dius.pact.provider</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit5</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.24</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

The tested event has a field in format "yyyy-mm". However, I get the following output:

```
    1.1) body: $.entity.month Expected "2023-02" to match a date of 'yyyy-MM-dd': Unable to parse the date: 2023-02
```

It seems that the field "format" of matcher is just ignored and the test expects a date in standard format.

I have tried to change the version of pact provider and consumer. But it didn't help at all. Can it be a Java version issue?

Expected behaviour: the test is green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved after I changed the version to 4.1.41.